# Expand one Expansion tile at a time

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a List of **Expansion tiles** with each of them containing a List of ListTile. Now what I want to do is collapse all expanded when clicking in one expansion tile. I want to only expand and display **one** expansion tile at a time. 
**Or** is there any way I can migrate this to **Expansion Panels**.

```
                      child: Card(
                            child: ExpansionTile(
                              key: _expansionKey,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
                              onExpansionChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() {
                                  preId = prescriptionProvider
                                      .doctorPrescriptions[index]
                                      .prescriptionId;
                                  fetchDoctorPrescriptionDrugsByDoctor(
                                      preId);
                                });
                                Toast.show("Changed", context);
                              },
                              title: Text("Prescription ID : " +
                                  prescriptionProvider
                                      .doctorPrescriptions[index]
                                      .prescriptionId),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {

                                  },
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: presciptionDrugList.length,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int i) {
                                      return ListTile(
                                        title: Text(
                                          presciptionDrugList.isNotEmpty
                                              ? presciptionDrugList[i]
                                                  .drugsName
                                              : "loading",
                                        ),
                                        trailing: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.pills),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

Since I have a single List array variable where I fetch the data for the ListTile opened tiles will show identical data to the one I am expanding.So, I want to hide this by collapsing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is a work around that will keep only one tile expanded. The problem with it that it is rebuilding the whole list each time one of the tiles being expanded.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    final int max = 10;
    int selected = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Builder(
        key: Key('builder ${selected.toString()}'),
        builder: (context){
          return ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                ExpansionTile(
                  key: Key(i.toString()),
                  title: Text('Tile ${i+1}'),
                  initiallyExpanded: i==selected,
                  onExpansionChanged: (expanded){
                    if(expanded)
                    setState(() {
                      selected = i; 
                    });
                    else setState(() {
                      selected = -1; 
                    });
                  },
                )
            ],
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The example seems to be working but I couldn't configure my app accordingly. Can you make it with the snippet I uploaded.

Comment: The example seems to be working but I couldn't configure my app accordingly. Can you make it with the snippet I uploaded.